# Which is better CTE or Inner-Selects in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, common-table-expression

Given below is a sample of my two *different query execution* with same *result*

The select *query* using *inner-select*.

```
   select p.product from
   (
      select * from tbl_a where productid not in (select productid from tbl_b)
   ) p 
   order by p.product
```

And select *query* using *CTE*.

```
   with cte as 
   (
   select * from tbl_a where productid not in (select productid from tbl_b)
   )
   select product from cte order by product
```

- So my question is *which among the above is good to use? And At what condition can use each of them?*

Answer (score 1):

Postgres always materializes CTEs, which means that the CTE version has additional overhead for reading and writing the data.  (Note:  this is not necessarily true in other databases.)  Postgres does not (necessarily) materialize subqueries, so that version should be faster.

A better way to write this query is to dispense with the subquery/CTE entirely:

```
  select a.product
  from tbl_a a
  where a.productid not in (select productid from tbl_b)
  order by a.product;
```

(I am ignoring whether `not exists` or `left outer join` would actually be better than `not in`.)

There is not a general rule for using CTEs instead of subqueries when writing queries.  It depends on a lot of factors, especially whether the underlying tables are indexed and how many times the CTE would appear in the query.