# concatenate rows in a table PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the table `cname`

```
CREATE TABLE cname
(
  cid integer,
  cname text,
  rel text
)
```

and these are some data in it.

```
INSERT INTO cname  VALUES (1, 'name1', 'a1');
INSERT INTO cname  VALUES (2, 'surname1', 'a1');
INSERT INTO cname  VALUES (3, 'name2', 'b2');
INSERT INTO cname  VALUES (4, 'surname2', 'b2');
```

and it look like this,

[image]

- for example, `rel` column data is same for both `cid` *1* and *2*
  so how can I concatenate both name in where `cid` in `(1,2)`

---

expecting reslut

```
cname
-----
surname1_name1
```

Note : while concatenate the filed `cname` the *surname* should come first, i.e in `rel` *a1* *group*
the max of cid (2) should consider first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your criteria you can do this in two ways..

Option 1 -  using [CTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html)

```
with cte as (
select cname,rel from cname order by cid desc
)
select string_agg(cname,'.') full_name from cte group by rel
```

Option 2 - using a sub select on *FROM Clause*

```
select string_agg(cname,'.') full_name
from (select cname,rel from cname order by cid desc) t  
group by rel
```

---

You can  [refer string_agg() and more..](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html)

Comment: may I know among those _two_ options which one is more better.... just interested to know ?

Comment: it depends.... just read this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25664457/3682599)

Comment: @WingedPanther In recent versions of postgres you do not need subselect to add ordering to aggregate. See: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES

Comment: @WingedPanther `string_agg(cname, '.' ORDER BY cid desc)`

Comment: @WingedPanther The feature is there from 9.0+ ... BTW I fixed my commetn